# How to perform actions in char linux driver when application crashes

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Let's assume that I have a char driver and during a process of some application, I send IOCTL that allocate some data, and the application crashes and the data will not release until the driver unloading.

There is an option to mark the application and when the application will crash to do some action in the driver?

Comment: When the process is ended, the driver should get a call to close.

Comment: How to catch this call?

Comment: @ItayAvraham I believe it's the same way you use use `ioctl`.

Comment: You didn't write a close call for your driver?

Comment: What i'm asking is if the driver will not unload, how can I arrive to the special close function in order to release the memory that belongs to the application that crashed?

Comment: It is better to associate the allocated data with the open file object rather than with the process. It is very hard for the char driver to tell when a process has ended, but it is very easy to tell when all references to the open file object have been released because your char driver's `release` handler will be called.

Comment: If the application process's file descriptors and mmap references for the file object opened by that process using your char driver have not been passed on to a child process where they remain open, then when your application process crashes, all those descriptors and mmap references will be released, causing your char driver's `release` handler to be called.

Comment: Unix files and devices get closed when the process calls `close()` or when it exits, which can happen either by calling `_exit()` or by receiving a fatal signal.  There wouldn't normally be any reason to distinguish those cases, and I'm not aware that the driver would be informed of the reason why the descriptor is being closed.  Why do you think that you would need to handle these cases differently?